# 301 Redirect via .htaccess php?i2=sajsak to productname.html - Not blanket

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

OK, so I'm trying to do a straight redirect:

store.php?StoreLevel=3&PrevStoreLevel=1&productid=6067&Level1=155&p=5&term=&BrowseBy=0

Redirected to:

mynewproductname.html

I'm not looking for a once size fits all rewrite rule, each one of these has a corresponding .html counter part, so kinda "hardcoded"

These are for 301's and Google Rankings

I can't figure this out. All resources I have found give me blanket rules on how to convert all php links in one shot to a html counterpart with the same name. I'm not looking to do this.

I've tried many things, none work. Some of my attempts:

RewriteRule ^store.php?StoreLevel=3&PrevStoreLevel=1&productid=6067&Level1=155&p=5&term=&BrowseBy=0 $ mynewproductname.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =store.php?StoreLevel=3&PrevStoreLevel=1&productid=6067&Level1=155&p=5&term=&BrowseBy=0
RewriteRule mynewproductname.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^StoreLevel=3&PrevStoreLevel=1&productid=6067&Level1=155&p=5&term=&BrowseBy=0$
RewriteRule ^store.php$ http://mysite.com/mynewproductname.html? [R=301,L]

Some of these cause a 500 server error, some just don't work. Assistance is greatly appreciated.

EDIT - mod_rewrite is on and working fine, was able to redirect:

RewriteRule ^foo$ http://mysite.com/testing.html [R=301,L]

With success

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .htaccess, you could try redirecting from within your .php file.  Have a lookup table of `productid` => webpage that gets scanned when the .php is first loaded; if you get a match, return a 301.  If you don't match, continue on with regular .php processing (or 404, as appropriate)

Comment: Thanks for the response. We need to follow Google's advice: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93633 So that we can maintain the current rankings, so doing this via htaccess is key.

Comment: Google's advice is to use a 301; it doesn't need to be done through .htaccess.  As far as the client/browser/spider is concerned, there is no difference as to how it is done.  If the redirect is different based on the productid, it is _much_ more efficient to run through PHP than to try to hack a working .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. So how would we go about this exactly? We have about 1900 rewrites (yikes I know!). We've spent the time to actually find a one to one match. So if we were doing this via php, is one php file for each link (1800)? Like: <?php
// Permanent redirection
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/newurlhere");
exit();
?>

Comment: I would use a database with a `redirect` table.  Columns would be `productid` and `webpage`.  Select `webpage` from the table based on `productid`; if you get a result, make your redirect.  If you don't get a result, send an error.